# Cannot convert *tls.listener to *net.TCPListener on golang

Tags: ssl, go

I created a TLS server on GO.

```
func main() {
    Log("Hello server!")

    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("cert.pem", "key.pem")
    if err != nil {
        Log("server: loadkeys: ", err);
        return;
    }

    config := tls.Config{Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert}}
    config.Rand = rand.Reader
    service := "0.0.0.0:9988"
    listener, err := tls.Listen("tcp", service, &config)
    if err != nil {
        Log("server: listen: %s", err)
        return
    }

    defer listener.Close()

    for {
        Log("Waiting for clients")

        connection, error := listener.Accept()
        if error != nil {
            Log("Client error: ", error)
        } else {
            //connection.SetLinger(0) //error here
            go ClientHandler(connection)
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot call SetLinger function, because tls.Listen function returns net.Listener. I need net.TCPListener.

I tried:

```
tpcListener := listener.(*net.TCPListener)
```

Error: panic: interface conversion: net.Listener is *tls.listener, not *net.TCPListener

There is ListenTCP on **net** package but there is not ListenTCP on **tls** package.

Answer (score 3):

You explicitly mention `SetLinger` but that's called on a `TCPConn` **not** on a `TCPListener`. Have you checked if the accepted `net.Conn` can be asserted to `*net.TCPConn`?

The `crypto/tls` package implements the `net.Listener` interface via a non-exported type so you cannot access the "inner" listener that way.

If you really need a `net.TCPListener`:
As with all the other Go standard packages that provide convenience functions that create listeners for you, there are lower level functions that let you create your own. So call `net.ListenTCP`, then whatever methods you like on it, then pass that to the `tls` package via [`tls.NewListener`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#NewListener).
See the [source for `crypto/tls`'s `Listen`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/f2e4c8b5fb3660d793b2c545ef207153db0a34b1/src/crypto/tls/tls.go#L69-L78) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is change:

```
listener, err := tls.Listen("tcp", service, &config)
```

to

```
listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", service)
```

Then you can call

```
 listener.(*net.TCPListener).SetDeadline(...)
 connection, err := listener.Accept()
 connection.(*net.TCPConn).SetLinger(9)
 tlsConn := tls.Server(conn, tlsConfig)
```